# Specify external resource in config.yml

Tags: r, yaml, rcharts

I have the following `config.yml` file:

```
dygraphs:
  jshead: [js/dygraph-combined.js, js/lodash.js]
  cdn:
    jshead:
      - "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.0.1/dygraph-combined.js"
      - "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"
```

It currently sources from the locally saved `js/dygraph-combined.js` and `js/lodash.js` files within my working directory.

How to rewrite it to source instead from the `http` addresses provided above?

**EDIT**

I've found a workaround without using `config.yml`, by inserting the addresses inside the `rCharts` object property like this:

```
dy1 <- rCharts$new()
...
dy1$html_assets$js = c(
 "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.0.1/dygraph-combined.js", 
 "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js")
...
```

This will result in `html` file that indeed contains the remote resources:

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.0.1/dygraph-combined.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Is there still a way how to achieve the same by amending the `config.yml` file appropriately?

Comment: You can pass the option `cdn = TRUE` to the `show` or `save` methods and it will automatically make use of the `http` links. For example, `dy1$show(cdn = TRUE)` or `dy1$save('mychart.html', cdn = TRUE)`.

Comment: thanks @Ramnath! Works like charm. Good to know `save` method for JS debugging too. If you copy above into a SO answer, I have no other option than to accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer.

You can pass the option cdn = TRUE to the show or save methods and it
will automatically make use of the http links. For example,

```
# display chart using http links
dy1$show(cdn = TRUE) 
# save chart using http links
dy1$save('mychart.html', cdn = TRUE)
```